# Create multiple threads/processes to execute individual python scripts on schedule

Tags: python, multithreading, process

I have multiple python files located in a local directory that I wish to run concurrently as separate threads or processes.

As of right now, I have the following pseudocode

```
def run_script(filePath, trigger):
   
    exec(open(filePath).read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
       for path in filePaths:
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_script, args=(path, trigger_sec))
            procs.append(proc)
            proc.start()

        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()
```

My question is: How do I add a scheduler/timer in the run_script function or somewhere else that tells the processes to exec that file every X seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you should look into using the `time` module. Try implementing something like this:

```
import time


def run_script(filePath, wait, amount):
    # Runs a file 'amount' times and waits for 'wait' seconds before running
    for _ in range(amount):
        time.sleep(wait)
        file = open(filePath, 'r')
        exec(file.read())
        file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
       for path in filePaths:
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_script, args=(path, wait, amount))
            procs.append(proc)
            proc.start()

        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()
```

Don't forget to close the file after opening it.